# DateTimePickerFormField not working in VS Code

Tags: flutter

Learning `Flutter` on my own and haven't gotten very far.  Using `VS Code` and trying to build a `DOB` widget with the `DateTimePickerFormField`.  I've got the `datetime_picker_formfield` library (`1.0.0`) in my `.packages` folder. I've imported it into my app file.  But I'm getting `"Undefined class"` error on my `DateTimePickerFormField` call and the library is identified as an `"unused import."` I've tried reloading the `windows` and restarting `VS code`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you've done so far, it would be helpful if you posted more information. For the time being, you can follow installation/usage guide posted by their developer

https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield

Comment: Here's my code:

DateTimePickerFormField createDobWidget() {
  return new DateTimePickerFormField(
    validator: (value) {
      if ((value == null)) {return 'Please enter your date of birth.';}
    },
    dateOnly: true,
    format: _dateFormat,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.date_range),
      hintText: 'Date',
      labelText: 'Select the Date'
    ),
    controller: _dobTextController
  );
}

Comment: The datetime_picker_formfield library is already imported. But I'm getting an error when I call the DateTimePickerFormField: VS Code is saying it's an undefined class because, I guess, it isn't recognizing the library has been imported?